# Delphi: Saving an array of objects to a file. (Serialization)

Tags: delphi, serialization, file-handling

I'm building a 3D application. I have a 3D layout(TLayout3D) on my form where I create and position TSpheres at run time. The Spheres are a part of a custom TNode class that I have created:

```
TNode = Class;

Sphere :TSphere;
ID :String;
NodeType :string;
TotalDistance :integer; //used in Dijkstras algorithm

End;
```

I have an array consisting of the TNode class

```
NodesArray : array [1..100] of TNode;
```

**I need to know how to save the array and then load it from a file so that I don't have to 'manually' create it again in the future.**

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: One way is to get rid of the array and use descendents of TCollection and TCollectionItem. With those, and the use of published properties, you get streaming and persistance almost for free :) That's what the IDE uses to handle arraylike properties of visual components.

Comment: Loads of different ways to do this. How do you want to do it? What is your preferred approach? Using a fixed length array isn't a great idea. What happens when you need more than 100 elements? Use a collection or a dynamic array, or `TList<T>`.

Comment: @Frazz thanks for the reply. If its not too much to ask can you give me a code example of your method?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I could use a dynamic array and then set the length later. I don't know know what you mean by my preferred approach. What would you recommend? I just need to save it and then load it after closing the program. Thank you for replying.

Comment: One obvious choice would be to use JSON. There are many many posts describing how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with David that JSON today would be a valid choice for persisting business objects and containers, I would like to post here the code to do it with TCollection and TCollectionItem. This is the old way that Delphi has used since ever, to stream out component properties to dfm files.

But there is a caveat here. I have tested this code and it does not work... not because it is broken (I have used similar code for years to persist business objects), but because the TSphere does not support the TPersistent Assign and AssignTo interface. For this to work the collection item's properties must be either simple data types and records, or proper TPersistent implementations. And TSphere is neither of these.

Anyway, here is the code:

**Interface**

```
Type
  TNode = Class(TCollectionItem)
  Private
    FSphere       : TSphere;
    FID           : String;
    FNodeType     : String;
    FTotalDistance: integer;
    Procedure SetSphere(Const Value: TSphere);
  Public
    Constructor Create(Collection: TCollection); Override;
    Destructor Destroy; Override;
    Procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); Override;
  Published
    Property Sphere       : TSphere Read FSphere Write SetSphere;
    Property ID           : String Read FID Write FID;
    Property NodeType     : String Read FNodeType Write FNodeType;
    Property TotalDistance: integer Read FTotalDistance Write FTotalDistance; // used in Dijkstras algorithm
  End;

Type
  TNodes = Class(TCollection)
  Private
    Function GetItem(Index: integer): TNode;
    Procedure SetItem(Index: integer; Value: TNode);
  Public
    Constructor Create; Reintroduce;
    Function Add: TNode;
    Procedure LoadFromFile(Const Filename: String);
    Procedure LoadFromStream(S: TStream);
    Procedure SaveToFile(Const Filename: String);
    Procedure SaveToStream(S: TStream);
    Property Items[Index: integer]: TNode Read GetItem Write SetItem; Default;
  End;

Type
  TNodesWrapper = Class(TComponent)
  Private
    FCollection: TNodes;
  Public
    Constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); Override;
    Destructor Destroy; Override;
  Published
    Property Collection: TNodes Read FCollection Write FCollection;
  End;
```

and **Implementation**

```
{ TNode }

Procedure TNode.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
Begin
  If Source Is TNode Then Begin
    If Assigned(Collection) Then
      Collection.BeginUpdate;
    Try
      Sphere        := TNode(Source).Sphere;
      ID            := TNode(Source).ID;
      NodeType      := TNode(Source).NodeType;
      TotalDistance := TNode(Source).TotalDistance;
    Finally
      If Assigned(Collection) Then
        Collection.EndUpdate;
    End;
  End
  Else
    Inherited;
End;

Constructor TNode.Create(Collection: TCollection);
Begin
  Inherited;
  FSphere := TSphere.Create(Nil);
  // Set default values here
End;

Destructor TNode.Destroy;
Begin
  FreeAndNil(FSphere);
  Inherited;
End;

Procedure TNode.SetSphere(Const Value: TSphere);
Begin
  FSphere.Assign(Value);
End;

{ TNodes }

Function TNodes.Add: TNode;
Begin
  Result := TNode(Inherited Add);
End;

Constructor TNodes.Create;
Begin
  Inherited Create(TNode);
End;

Function TNodes.GetItem(Index: integer): TNode;
Begin
  Result := TNode(Inherited GetItem(Index));
End;

Procedure TNodes.LoadFromFile(Const Filename: String);
Var
  S: TFileStream;
Begin
  S := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmOpenRead);
  Try
    LoadFromStream(S);
  Finally
    S.Free;
  End;
End;

Procedure TNodes.LoadFromStream(S: TStream);
Var
  Wrapper: TNodesWrapper;
  SBin   : TMemoryStream;
Begin
  SBin    := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Wrapper := TNodesWrapper.Create(Nil);
  Try
    ObjectTextToBinary(S, SBin);
    SBin.Position := 0;
    SBin.ReadComponent(Wrapper);
    Assign(Wrapper.Collection);
  Finally
    Wrapper.Free;
    SBin.Free;
  End;
End;

Procedure TNodes.SaveToFile(Const Filename: String);
Var
  S: TStream;
Begin
  S := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmCreate);
  Try
    SaveToStream(S);
  Finally
    S.Free;
  End;
End;

Procedure TNodes.SaveToStream(S: TStream);
Var
  Wrapper: TNodesWrapper;
  SBin   : TMemoryStream;
Begin
  SBin    := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Wrapper := TNodesWrapper.Create(Nil);
  Try
    Wrapper.Collection.Assign(Self);
    SBin.WriteComponent(Wrapper);
    SBin.Position := 0;
    ObjectBinaryToText(SBin, S);
  Finally
    Wrapper.Free;
    SBin.Free;
  End;
End;

Procedure TNodes.SetItem(Index: integer; Value: TNode);
Begin
  Inherited SetItem(Index, Value);
End;

{ TNodesWrapper }

Constructor TNodesWrapper.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
Begin
  Inherited;
  FCollection := TNodes.Create;
End;

Destructor TNodesWrapper.Destroy;
Begin
  FreeAndNil(FCollection);
  Inherited;
End;
```

TCollections are still being used albeit some of this code might look strange to someone used to using generic containers... most of it has to do with typecasting and linking one TCollectionItem class to its specific TCollection class.

The magic happens in the Stream ReadComponent and WriteComponent methods. Unfortunately, since a TCollection is not a TComponent, it must be wrapped in a TComponent... and that is what the TNodesWrapper is for.

It may look strange and complex, but most of this can be abstracted in a general purpose TCollection descendant that adds the ability to Load and Save to File/Stream/String. And so most of this code can be hidden under the hood.

And... I repeat... **this only works if the properties you want to persist are per se persistable**... and TSphere is not. So I now wonder how FireMonkey 3D forms persist them, as I haven't actually developed 3D apps yet.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use arrays and static sized/binded things at all! Apply the one responsibility rule. Create serializers for your entities. In this case you can change your mind and create any number of serializers for any formats. Your code get more flexible, changeable and testable.

```
TSphere = class
  // Entity. Just fields with getter/setter methods
end;

TContext = TDictionary<string><TObject>;

CONST_ctxkey_Factory = 'factory';

IStream = interface (IInvokable )
  procedure load( var data_; size_ : cardinal );
  procedure store( var data_; size_ : cardinal );
end;

ISerializer = interface ( TInvokable )
  procedure load( ctx_ : TContext );
  procedure store( ctx_ : TContext );
end;

TSerializer = class ( TInterfaceObject, ISerializer )
  protected
    // Attributes
    fObject : TObject;
    fStream : IStream;

  public
    constructor create( object_ : TObject; stream_ : IStream );

    // Realized methods (ISerializer)
    procedure load( ctx_ : TContext ); virtual; abstract;
    procedure store( ctx_ : TContext ); virtual; abstract;        
end;

TSphereSerializer_XML = class ( TSerializer )
  public
    // Overriden methods
    procedure load( ctx_ : TContext ); override;
    procedure store( ctx_ : TContext ); override;      
end;

TSpheresMainSerializer_BIN = class ( TSerializer )
  public
    // Overriden methods
    procedure load( ctx_ : TContext ); override;
    procedure store( ctx_ : TContext ); override;
end;

TSpheresMainSerializer_BIN.store( ctx_ : TContext );
var
  spheres : TSphereList;
  sf : TSerializerContext;
  sph : TSphere;
  iSe : ISerializer;
begin
  spheres := TSphereList( fObject );
  sf := ctx_.items[CONST_ctxkey_Factory];
  fStream.write( version_number, sizeOf( cardinal ) );
  fStream.write( spheres.count, sizeOf( cardinal ) );
  for sph in shperes_ do
  begin
    iSe := sf.createShpereSerializer( sph );
    iSe.store( ctx );
  end;
end;

TSphereSerializer_BIN = class ( TSerializer )
  public
    // Overriden methods
    procedure load( ctx_ : TContext ); override;
    procedure store( ctx_ : TContext ); override;
end;

TSphereList = TList<TSphere>;

TSerializerFactory = class
  public
    // It creates serializers for XML format
    function createContext : TContext; virtual;
    function createSpheresMainSerializer( spheres_ : TSphereList; stream_ : IStream ) : ISerializer; virtual; abstract;
    function createSphereSerializer( sphere_ : TSphere; stream_ : IStream ) : ISerializer; virtual; abstract;
end;

TSerializerFactory_BIN = class ( TSerializerFactory )
  public
    // It creates serializers for binary format
    function createSpheresMainSerializer( spheres_ : TSphereList; stream_ : IStream ) : ISerializer; override;
    function createSphereSerializer( sphere_ : TSphere; stream_ : IStream ) : ISerializer; override;
end;

function TSerializerFactory_BIN.createSpheresMainSerializer( spheres_ : TSphereList; stream_ : IStream ) : ISerializer; 
begin
  result := TSpheresMainSerializer_BIN.create( TObject( spheres_ ), stream_ );
end;

function TSerializerFactory_BIN.createSphereSerializer( sphere_ : TSphere; stream_ : IStream ) : ISerializer; 
begin
  result := TSphereSerializer_BIN.create( sphere_, stream_ );
end;
```

The output file format of the next procedure depends on the TSerializerFactory passed as a parameter (sf_):

```
procedure saveSpheresToStream( spheres_ : TSphereList; stream_ : IStream; sf_ : TSerializerFactory );
var
  ctx : TContext;
  iSe : ISerializer;
begin
  try
    ctx := sf_.createContext;
    ctx.add( CONST_ctxkey_Factory, sf_ );
    try
      iSe := sf_.createSpheresMainSerializer( spheres_, stream_ );
      iSe.store( ctx );
    finally
      ctx.free;
    end;
end;
```

I know it was too thick, still too long for at first sight... but maybe usefull! :)